# Inconsistent datatype: lob type comparision in sap hana

Tags: hana, cdata

I wanted to see the xml files of information views that are stored in cdata column of `_SYS_REPO.ACTIVE_OBJECT` in SAP HANA.

But unfortunately, when I'm trying to filter cdata empty values, it's throwing the below error:

> Inconsistent datatype: lob type comparison.

Query used to filter and view CDATA column are:

```
SELECT top 10  CDATA FROM _SYS_REPO.ACTIVE_OBJECT where cdata is not null
SELECT top 10  CDATA FROM _SYS_REPO.ACTIVE_OBJECT where cdata !=''
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like we cant use comparison operations with lob data type in sap HANA. However, we can use **LIKE** operator with lob datatypes.

Working query is:
`SELECT top 10 CDATA FROM _SYS_REPO.ACTIVE_OBJECT where cdata not like ''`
 and it returns the non empty records.